# Looking for title of a sci-fi story about a one-way space journey

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a Sci-Fi story (probably pre-1990) where a group is sent off into deep space and I *believe* unbeknownst to them it's a one-way journey.

In the course of the journey they all become very intelligent, they make psychoactive drugs from the plants on board, I recall that they discovered it's a one-way journey to test the affects of space travel, and they redesign/refit their engines and return to Earth.

Lame recall, sorry, that's all I got. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe. But they don't seem an exact match, and unless they are confirmed to be, we generally don't close story-IDs as duplicates for a few similarities

Comment: They seem identical. If the OP confirms that it's *not* the same, I will remove my close vote (as well as being most surprised)

Comment: [Confirmed by @Aqwerty that it is indeed *The Gold at the Starbow’s End*](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/51585/440).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - I don't see any such confirmation at that link...

Comment: @SSumner: Aqwerty added an answer to that question confirming that *The Gold at the Starbow’s End* was the story in question. Looks like it’s been removed, quite correctly, due to not being an answer.

Comment: Ahhh. That makes more sense

Answer (score 8):

I believe you're thinking of a 1982 novel by Frederik Pohl called [*Starburst*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Starburst-Frederik-Pohl/dp/0345301951), which was expanded from the short story "The Gold at the Starbow's End".

To quote from the blurb on the Amazon link:

> The crew of the *Constitution*--scientists cum astronauts--had been carefully screened for extremely high intelligence and superb physical qualities. They were to be the first explorers sent to another stellar system. There they would explore the planet Alpha-Aleph and then return. They were the toast of the world press--true heroes, for they were to go where no man had gone before.
>
> Or so they thought.
>
> Dr. Dieter von Knefhausen knew otherwise--for there was no planet, no place to go...and no place from which to return. Knefhuasen had planned it that way. Of course, Knefhausen realized his plan wasn't exactly ethical. But then, he knew the ends often justify the means.
>
> And Knefhausen's plan worked better then even he had ever hoped!

[image: Starburst]