# Novel with humans travelling to a distant planet becoming super-intelligent

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-exploration, mathematics

I'm trying to find the name of a novel (or was it a short story) where a group of humans travel to a distant planet and along the way (through genetics?) become more and more intelligent. I seem to recall that at some point they send back one of their who's a little less bright. Also, they send communications coded with some mathematical factorization that takes humans a long time to decrypt.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you remember when you read it? What language was it written in?

Comment: How many "Starburst" questions does this make?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's *Starburst* by Frederik Pohl, an expansion of his earlier story "The Gold at the Starbow's End". All of the elements you mention are in the novel. It's come up [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2697/story-featuring-smart-people-sent-on-a-space-mission-to-nowhere/2711#2711) [before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51577/looking-for-title-of-a-sci-fi-story-about-a-one-way-space-journey/51578#51578).

[image: Cover of "Starburst" by Frederik Pohl. The cover shows a spaceship heading towards a rainbow-colored circle of light, against a starry space background.]

Comment: Since you know this is a duplicate, why not mark it as such rather than answering again?